# Php script to search for images and return the url

Tags: php, image, programming-languages

I have made a crazy (?) thought right now...

Is there any script written in PHP that gets a given keyword and returns a url of a relative image? (from google, yahoo, etc)

If so, may I have an example? And if not, hwo can this be made?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Flicker API](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/). [phpFlickr](http://phpflickr.com/) seems to be an existing PHP library.

Comment: Hey, thanks! What I am searching is something really really simple. Just a textbox for the input and the result in a submitted form...

Comment: @Mairoula You will be able to build that with the API.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the PHP's CURL functions to do that, just google it and read the PHP manual.

Comment: curl_init(),curl_setopt(),curl_exec(),curl_close(), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one
Demo : http://www.scriptbaba.com/demos/get_images/

http://www.scriptbaba.com/details-php-image-search-api-25.html